# Is there a way to detect if an element was clicked by jQuery's click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bots

I'm not too sure if this is possible, but is there anyway of achieving this? I want to have some basic protection from scripts that will automatically register click events on my buttons, e.g.: pesky bots.

I want to only allow clicks with the mouse, not clicks triggered by javascript itself.

Any ideas or other methods of protection against this?

Comment: Please try better to explain the exact outcome your seeking

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to identify that the click event has triggered through element click or through any js code, right?

In that case you can use "event" object returned by "click" event

You can use

```
event.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')
```

above statement returns true if the event is triggered by clicking on target element else returns false

Comment: @Justin - A click that is simulated with `dispatchEvent()` can be made to have the originalEvent property even though it isn't a real mouse click.  See jsFiddle for demo (in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/h7pVq/.  So how well this approach works depends upon how the outside agent simulates the click.

Answer (score 3):

Note: Note sure how foolproof is this.

There is an originalEvent property that will be set when the user triggers the click event, so you can check it I think

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    console.log(e, this, e.originalEvent)
    if(e.originalEvent){
        console.log('user clicked')
    }
}).click();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kyDdd/)

Answer (score 3):

You can register a mouseDown event handler on the button and only process the `.click()` event if the `.click()` event occurs within a certain time after the mouseDown (e.g. a second).

```
function now() {
    return (new Date()).getTime();
}

$("#myButton").on("mousedown click", function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    if (e.type === "mousedown") {
        self.data("mousedownTime", now()); 
    } else {
        var mouseTime = self.data("mousedownTime");
        if (mouseTime && now() - mouseTime < 1000) {
            // process the click here
        }
    }
});
```

This could be turned into a jQuery plugin method that would do this for you, fairly easily.

```
jQuery.fn.realClick = function(fn) {
    this.on("mousedown click", function(e) {
        var self = $(this);
        if (e.type === "mousedown") {
            self.data("mousedownTime", now()); 
        } else {
            var mouseTime = self.data("mousedownTime");
            if (mouseTime && now() - mouseTime < 1000) {
                // process the real click here
                return fn(e);
            }
        }
    });
}

$("#myButton").realClick(function(e) {
    // your click processing code here
    // only gets called if a click event was
    // preceded by a mousedown event within 1 second
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to achieve this is using Google Analytics. Something like the below maybe, tweaked to your goals?

```
<p class="downloadsmall">download: <a href="jpg/LOW/1.jpg" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/img/LowRes/1.jpg']);">Low Res</a></p>


<!-- GA track all onClicks -->

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'YOUR COOL GA ID']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', '/downloads/img/"+x+"']);

$(function(){
    $('.downloadsmall a').on("click", function(){
        var theHREF = $(this).attr('href'),
            myGAQ   = _gaq || [];
        myGAQ.push(['_trackPageview', theHREF]);
        myGAQ.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'JPG', theHREF]);

    });
});

</script>

<!-- End GA track all onClicks -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted).

> The isTrusted read-only property of the Event interface is a Boolean that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via EventTarget.dispatchEvent().

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("click-me").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.isTrusted) {
    console.log("This click is real");
  } else {
    console.log("This click is not real");
  }
});

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("click-me").click()
});
```

```html
<button id="click-me">Click me</button>
<button id="test">Click to simulate click on the other button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
$('#id').on('click', function(){
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

I'm not sure if I 100% understand your question. That would obviously log something if it was clicked. Are you looking for a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: I mean to specifically tell if an element was clicked with just jQuery's .click(). I want to know if it was clicked by the user with their mouse. I probably should have explained that better.

Comment: Well then the code about will do that. It console logs 'clicked' whenever a user clicks on the element with that id.

Comment: jQuery does all it can to make the `.click()` function emmit as natural events as possible (source: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). SO it may get hard to distinguish it. You could, however, override the `.click`()`method in your script.

Comment: @TylerMcGinnis: it's not about getting notified of a click, it's about telling apart "natural/real" clicks form automatic ones.

Comment: @JohannesH. got it. Definitely not my answer then. Thanks for clarifying.